# I have a deprecation error occuring on PHP 7.4.3

Tags: php, deprecation-warning, php-7.4

I am a beginner in php. I am running the final chapter project named Robin's Nest from the book "Learning PHP, MySQL and JavaScript with jQuery".

In the file **function.php**, the function `sanitizeString` raises the following deprecation error:

> Deprecated: Function get_magic_quotes_gpc() is deprecated in C:\xampp2\htdocs\MyProjects\robinsnest\functions.php on line 42.

My version of php is 7.4.3 and I use Xampp on Windows 10 operating system. I checked the PHP manual for the function and saw that the function has been **deprecated** as of PHP 7.4.0.

How can I modify this function so that it doesn't use the deprecated function `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` and still get equivalent functionality as there seem to be no replacement function?

```
 function sanitizeString($var)
  {
    global $connection;
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
      $var = stripslashes($var);
    return $connection->real_escape_string($var);
  }
```

Comment: Just get rid of that whole `if` statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Use prepared statements instead of string escaping - the latter misses some cases and can cause security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @halfer, when you run the Robin's Nest thing in localhost? Is it very slow?

Comment: @deanstreet: I think you intended your query for the author of this question, Rilwan Smith (my account is attached to the question because I edited it).

Comment: @Rilwan Smith When you run the Robin's Nest thing, do you find it very slow?

Comment: no it wasn't slow.@deanstreet

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, however the other question is a duplicate of this question.This post was asked on April 3 2020 whereas the other post was asked on April 6 2020.

Answer (score 3):

Just get rid of the code that uses the function. It hasn't been relevant for many versions.

```
 function sanitizeString($var)
  {
    global $connection;
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    return $connection->real_escape_string($var);
  }
```

Note that this sanitization is not appropriate to begin with. `htmlentities()` should only be used when you're displaying data on a web page, not when you're processing input. And `$connection->real_escape_string()` should only be used when substituting variables into a SQL string, but it's better to use prepared statements for this.